# Shell: how to get name of included file?

Tags: shell, include, filenames

I couldn't really find a solution of my simple problem... Need your help.
So..

I have two files:

- run.sh:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  # include file my.sh
  . my.sh
  ```
- my.sh:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  # Show my filename
  echo "$0"
  ```

And run command:

```
# sh run.sh
```

And result:

```
run.sh
```

But I'm expecting included filename:

```
my.sh
```

**So the question is how to get CURRENT filename?**
Big thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In BASH you can use:

```
echo "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
```

Comment: Recommend you add more, it's been flagged.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Does exists any cross-platform solution?

Comment: I've found expanded answer.
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in)